# Where is System.GetField?

Tags: script#

I have created a ScriptSharp project in Visual Studio Web Express 2012 and version 0.7.6 of ScriptSharp was assumed.

I have some classes that uses Type.SetField and Type.GetField but I am receiveing an error: 
'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetField'

Where is System.Type.GetField ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `GetField()` and `SetField()` in the public static `System.Script` class for newer Versions of Script#.

Comment: Thanks, But I am having problems with Script.Alert and Script.Literal. Where can I find a summary of these updates ???

Comment: If I use System.Script.SetField the compiler gives a message: Check that your C# source compiles and that you are not using an unsupported feature. It is breaking all my old classes.

Comment: See https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/cc/History.txt for on-going list of changes. Script.Alert -> Window.Alert. Script.Literal is unchanged. Don't use namespace-qualified names. I believe the compiler error message says exactly that.